# How to terminate scanner when user enters 0

Tags: java

I am writing a program that reads unspecified number of integers from a user. It tells the number of **positive** and **negative** integers, computes the sum and average of all the integers entered.
**When user enters 0, that's the end of input.** Someone should help me out

Comment: Take a look at example 4 from duplicate (you may need to refresh this page to see link to duplicate question - it should be placed at top of your question).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exit your read operation when user enter 0,

> Sample code

```
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    int no = sc. nextInt();
    if(no == 0) { // when zero is there break loop
        break;
    }
    //operate
}
```